# How to load specific keyword or line only from a properties file without loading full properties file in java

Tags: java, properties, loading, properties-file

Is there any way to load specific type of keyword only from properties file ?
I don't want to load entire properties file just need to load specific key matching lines.For example, We have below properties file :

```
server.host=bharat.corp.com   
server.user=kumar  
server.pwd=password123  
emp.name=M.W.Khan   
emp.id=230989    
emp.address=Birsingpur
```

in above properties i wanted to load only keys starting from emp instead loading all property including server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `spring-boot` you can use annotations:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "emp")
```

Comment: I guess this annotation i.e @ConfigurationProperties is available in spring boot not in spring, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Configurationproperties is working fine but my expectation is little more, While using configurationproperties i need to mention all the keys after "emp" to get the values but suppose if we don't know the keys after prefix. I know only prefix not after prefix but i should be able to read all key=values having "emp" prefix.  Any lead ?